# Why won't my Lego Mindstorms NXT stop beeping/clicking and work properly?

Tags: nxt

I was trying to update the firmware on my NXT but suddenly the screen went blank and it started beeping. I unplugged and re-plugged my USB and a notification came up saying that the device malfunctioned. I tried holding down the orange button but that didn't work so then I held down the off button (gray button) but that didn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: I advise that you look at our other questions about malfunctioning NXTs for more troubleshooting tips here: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nxt

Comment: Btw, did the beeping sound like computer mouse clicks? If so, then this means that the firmware has been broken in some way. Here's another troubleshooting idea: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/8076/15028

Comment: yes it dose sound a little like clicking

Comment: Click the [link](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/8076/15028) in my second comment for instructions on fixing the problem. If it doesn't help, let us know. Clicking NXT bricks are actually quite common.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it

Comment: How?? Please write how you fixed it as an answer so that this question doesn't get considered an "unanswered question."